# Simplifying if else statements

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement, highcharts, lodash

Hi I have a json data as below:

```
{
    "details":
        {
            "data1": 
                {
                    "monthToDate":1000,                   
                    "firstLastMonth":"December",
                    "firstLastMonthAmount":5000,
                    "secondLastMonth":"November",
                    "secondLastMonthAmount":12000
                },
            "data2":
                {
                    "monthToDate":4000,                   
                    "firstLastMonth":"December",
                    "firstLastMonthAmount":10000,
                    "secondLastMonth":"November",
                    "secondLastMonthAmount":15000
                },
           "data3":
                {
                    "monthToDate":2000,                   
                    "firstLastMonth":"December",
                    "firstLastMonthAmount":8000,
                    "secondLastMonth":"November",
                    "secondLastMonthAmount":12000
                }
        }   
}
```

And I have typescript if statements below,

```
....
Object.values(data.details.data1).map(obj => {
                if (obj === 'January') {
                    xAxisTranslatedArray.push(this.JAN);
                } else if (obj === 'February') {
                    xAxisTranslatedArray.push(this.FEB);
                } else if (obj === 'March') {
                    xAxisTranslatedArray.push(this.MAR);
                } else if (obj === 'April') {
                    xAxisTranslatedArray.push(this.APR);
                } else if (obj === 'May') {
                    xAxisTranslatedArray.push(this.MAY);
                } else if (obj === 'June') {
                    xAxisTranslatedArray.push(this.JUN);
                } else if (obj === 'July') {
                    xAxisTranslatedArray.push(this.JUL);
                } else if (obj === 'August') {
                    xAxisTranslatedArray.push(this.AUG);
                } else if (obj === 'September') {
                    xAxisTranslatedArray.push(this.SEP);
                } else if (obj === 'October') {
                    xAxisTranslatedArray.push(this.OCT);
                } else if (obj === 'November') {
                    xAxisTranslatedArray.push(this.NOV);
                } else if (obj === 'December') {
                    xAxisTranslatedArray.push(this.DEC);
                }
            });
```

Am using lodash, highcharts  and i18n translations. So each of my `this.MONTH` is i18n keys. I can't directly pass the values since not able to translate them. So I needed to push to an array each values and pass into highchart's X-axis. My question is basically when I see the if else statements it looks too long and kind of repetitive. Is there any short cut here? Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: could `obj` have a different value than a month?

Comment: Remove `if-else` and use `switch-case`

Comment: I don't get it. This seems to be the perfect case for a `switch-case`. The only answer, stating this, gets downvoted and deleted? Why?!

Comment: @wλnnλhug:  I'd say a switch-case is excessively verbose, because it still requires multiple calls to `xAxisTranslatedArray.push`.

Comment: @Cerbrus while I agree with you about the verbose part, you can reduce the code to one call to push, using a variable to store the value defined by the `switch-case`.

Comment: @SergeK.: Still more verbose than a simple map :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a separate map object:

```
const months = {
    January: this.JAN,
    February: this.FEB,
    March: this.MAR,
    // etc,
}

Object.values(data.details.data1).forEach(obj => {
    if (months[obj]) {
        xAxisTranslatedArray.push(months[obj]);
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can replace the `if` with a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
Object.values(data.details.data1)
    .filter(obj => months[obj])
    .forEach(obj => xAxisTranslatedArray.push(months[obj]));
```

Also, note that I'm using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). `map` is used to modify an array, but you're only iterating over an array. `forEach` is the semantically correct choice there.

Comment: I would prefer to `filter` first and then `map`.

Comment: @HenrikR: Why `map`? That said, updated the answer with a `filter` / `forEach` option.

Comment: Because you can now use `map` and return the desired array :)
Change last row to `.map(obj => months[obj]);` and get returned value

Comment: @HenrikR: True, but then you'd have to concat to or override `xAxisTranslatedArray`. Depends on whether `xAxisTranslatedArray` already contains data.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `bracket` notation.

Also, use `substring` or `slice` methods in order to get first `three` characters.

Also, don't forget to check if `obj` is a `string`.

```
var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
if(typeof obj === 'string' && months.includes(obj))
    xAxisTranslatedArray.push(this[obj.substring(0,3).toUpperCase()]);
```

Comment: getting an error as `Error TypeError: t.substring is not a function`

Comment: @chewi, it's `obj.substring`, not `t.substring`

Comment: Considering we're iterating over a set of values parsed from unknown json data, you can't even assume `obj` is a string. For the example data, we're mapping over `[1000, "December", 5000, "November", 12000]`. Numbers don't have a `subString` method.

Comment: @Cerbrus, that's not true. In the example `obj` is an entire object from the array and OP must choose one field.

Comment: Read the question again. What is the `Object.values(data.details.data1)` we're iterating over?

Comment: @Cerbrus, yes, you're right, thank you for your point. I updated the answer with a easily check.

Comment: Okay, it works now, but the same concern as with gurvinder's answer: There's no clear connection between `this.JAN` and `"January"` It still depends on some string manipulation, while you're really just getting a static set of strings...

Comment: @Cerbrus *It still depends on some string manipulation, while you're really just getting a static set of strings* So? These are not any random strings, they are picked up from an array.

Comment: @gurvinder372: so why not _directly_ pick the resulting value from a map, instead of first looking through an array, then getting the value?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a map definition, like so:

```
let mapping = {};
mapping['January'] = this.JAN;
... // rest of definitions.


Object.values(data.details.data1).forEach(obj => {
              if(mapping[obj]){
                  xAxisTranslatedArray.push(mapping[obj]);
              });
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `obj`'s **first three characters converted to uppercase** is what you want as a key, try

```
var monthArray = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
Object.values( data.details.data1 ).forEach(obj => {
   if ( monthArray.indexOf( obj ) != -1 )
   {
      xAxisTranslatedArray.push(this[ obj.substring(0,3).toUpperCase() ]);
   }
});
```

Comment: @Cerbrus Can you elaborate more? Do you feel that in some browser or environment it will give unexpected values?

Comment: Considering we're iterating over a set of values parsed from unknown json data, you can't even assume `obj` is a string. For the example data, we're mapping over `[1000, "December", 5000, "November", 12000]`. Numbers don't have a `subString` method.

Comment: @Cerbrus Got it, I am now using a month array. Basically I noticed that OP is iterating all values of `data1`  and not just a specific key of `data1`.

Comment: @Cerbrus How is that?

Comment: Just my opinion, but there's still no clear, obvious connection between `this.JAN` and `"January"`. It still depends on some string manipulation, while you're really just getting a static set of strings...

Comment: @Cerbrus Connection is explicitly given in OP's code. And yes - there is some string manipulation. But I don't why you are saying as if it is a **bad thing**. I am setting static set of strings based on the connection between them and `this` properties given in OP's code.